# How to make fresh new hard drive partitions during ubuntu installation

Tags: partitioning

Currently I have no partitions only a single 500(488)GB drive. I want to format the hard drive and make fresh new partitions.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

During the installation, it will ask how to partition the disk.  Just chose "Something Else".  You can then do whatever you want.  Okay, granted, that tool isn't the greatest, but for simple partitioning it will do.

Alternatively, boot the LiveUSB/CD to desktop and launch gparted to make the partitioning scheme you want (or use the command line, or whatever you are familiar with).  Then during the installation, again select "Something Else" and use the partitions: right-click on the partition to change their mountpoints, etc...